# Can't upgrade Jackson jars used by webapp running on glassfish

Tags: rest, jackson, jersey, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

We have a REST-based web application that used to run on Tomcat using relatively new versions of Jersey (2.25.1) and Jackson (2.8.10).  These libraries were bundled in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the war, and things worked well.

Due to program requirements, we were forced to migrate to glassfish.  We're using the "web profile" version of glassfish 4.1.2 and are running into some problems.  We were only able to get the webapp working by downgrading Jersey and Jackson to versions that match glassfish 4.1.2 (Jersey 2.21 and Jackson 2.5.1).  In addition, we had to add a missing Jackson jar to the glassfish/modules directory, namely **jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.5.1.jar**

Other posts suggested "upgrading" Jackson by replacing the jars in the glassfish/modules directory with the latest versions.  HOWEVER, if we do that, the commands to start/stop the domain throw exceptions.  For instance, running "startserv.bat" results in the following:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.reader.ProgressStatusDTOJsonProprietaryReader.<clinit>(ProgressStatusDTOJsonProprietaryReader.java:57)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.reader.ProprietaryReaderFactory.<clinit>(ProprietaryReaderFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain$2.run(AdminMain.java:272)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 4 more
```

Is there any way to use the versions of Jackson and/or Jersey that we want, or are we forced to use whatever version comes bundled with glassfish?  Also, are we forced to "patch" glassfish by copying in the missing Jackson annotations jar?

Comment: You say that you've been forced to migrate to GlassFish - have you considered Payara Server? (disclaimer: am employee) It's derived from (and therefore fully compatible with) GlassFish and the latest 4.1.2.173 version [includes Jackson 2.8.8](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/master/nucleus/pom.xml#L193). It's completely open source and free to use so you should just be able to drop it in to replace GlassFish and continue as normal. https://www.payara.fish/downloads

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it!  I'm not sure if it's an option for our project, but for the purposes of this thread, let's assume it's not allowed.